# What would be the server configuration to support 50 thousand users for a Jhipster App? Any thoughts?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

Can anyone share some thoughts on what could be the server configuration to support around 50 thousand users in a day for a Jhipster Application.

Please find the below .yo-rc.json configuration for the application.

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.12.2",
    "baseName": "xyz",
    "packageName": "com.xyz.xyz",
    "packageFolder": "com/xyz/xyz",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Still you need read about Jhipster, there is no configuration required for the visitors clicks. And for now we don't have that feature.

Comment: It highly depends on what your users do, proportion of write versus read operations on database, how many concurrent users at same time, etc... Having "hibernateCache": "no" could be a problem for scaling up. Use gatling to get an idea of your app performance.